# simple php to return an image returns an error

Tags: php, httpwebrequest

Trying to simply get an image returned. But the following returns an error 'An error occured.' Is it possible I need to configure php on my server differently?

```
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
// get bytearray
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

// add headers for download dialog-box
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
echo $im;
}  else echo 'An error occured.';


?>
```

Comment: Short answer: `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` is not set.
To see the long (and helpful) answer, you'll have to provide more info... For instance, how is this script being called?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

[The manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) states that it's best to use `php://input` [(man)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) to read the raw post data. Also, neither `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` nor `php://input` will be available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Ahh... `enctype` is different from `Content-type`. Being flash-phobic, I can't guess the inner workings of that actionscript, but [this post](http://charlescfenwick.com/blog/?p=5) suggests setting the `Enctype` header also:

`jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader('Enctype', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Comment: I'm using "Content-type", "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0):

grossvogel, in Actionscript

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("myPHPthatisbroken.php?name=myreturnedJpg.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);  
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

Comment: This probably should be added as part of the question.... I updated my answer based on this input, though.